# HTML Form sending an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that looks like the following:

```
<form action="results.php" method="get">

<input type='checkbox' name='batch[]' value='1'>
<input type='text' name='job_id[]' value='111'>

<br>

<input type='checkbox' name='batch[]' value='1'>
<input type='text' name='job_id[]' value='999'>

</br>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>

</form>
```

[image]

In the example below I have only selected the row with 999 in the textbook.

The results are displayed in the results.php page which code looks like this:

```
<?php

$batch = $_GET['batch'];
$job_id = $_GET['job_id'];

foreach($job_id as $key => $value) {

    echo $batch[$key]." ";
    echo $value."<br>";
    }

?>
```

The above code displays like this:

```
1 111
999
```

As you can see the 1 (checkbox) is next to 111. I want to be able to allow send across the job_id from the row selected.

Hopefully I have explained the problem well enough.

Many thanks,

John

Comment: See this: [https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/](https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add index number in html :

```
<form action="viewport.php" method="get">

    <input type='checkbox' name='batch[1]' value='1'>
    <input type='text' name='job_id[1]' value='111'>

    <br>

    <input type='checkbox' name='batch[2]' value='1'>
    <input type='text' name='job_id[2]' value='999'>

    </br>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>

</form>



<?php
if(isset($_GET['batch'])) {
  $batch = $_GET['batch'];
  $job_id = $_GET['job_id'];
  foreach($job_id as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($batch[$key])) {
      echo $batch[$key]." ";
      echo $value."<br>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

It will only print:

```
1 999
```

because only second check-box is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Give textbox value to checkbox. Same value set to checkbox and textbox.

**Javascript**

```
<form action="test5.php" method="get">

<input type='checkbox' name='batch[]' value='111'>
<input type='text' name='job_id[]' value='111'>

<br>

<input type='checkbox' name='batch[]' value='999'>
<input type='text' name='job_id[]' value='999'>

</br>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$batch = $_GET['batch'];
$job_id = $_GET['job_id'];

foreach($batch as $key => $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
    }

?>
```